# Has Many associations with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

```
factory :account do
end

factory :user do 
  account
end

factory :user2 do 
  account
end


factory :location do
  // how to add to the users has_many collection?
end
```

My Location model has a `has_many :users` association, how can I add user and user2 to that collection in my factories?

Also when building an object graph, should factory_girl be used just to create an Account, User but not actually build the relation between the two?  Should I be doing that myself in my tests or some kind of helper?
Because say I want to create account1 and account2, and each account has a location.  I have to build this object graph myself within my tests then right?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `after` callback:

```
factory :location do
  after(:create) do |location, evaluator|
    create(:user, location: location)
    create(:user2, location: location)
  end
end
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

Answer (score 1):

you can create 2 users at once:

```
factory :location do
  after(:create) do |location|
    create_list(:user, 2, location: location)
  end
end
```